# How to select an OVERRIDE_SRCDIR custom source code for GCC when building Buildroot?

Tags: buildroot

I've been using the `BR2_PACKAGE_OVERRIDE_FILE` + `<pkg>_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR` settings in Buildroot 2018.05 to successfully track packages of interest such as Binutils and glibc as submodules my projet:

```
BINUTILS_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../../submodules/binutils-gdb
GLIBC_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../../submodules/glibc
```

However, when I tried an analogous procedure for GCC, it didn't seem to take effect:

```
GCC_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../../submodules/gcc
```

For example, under `build/` in the build folder, I get the usual:

```
host-gcc-final-7.3.0
host-gcc-initial-7.3.0
```

instead of the expected `-custom` versions.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Maybe http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/Internal-toolchain-wrapper-ccache-fixes-tp113064p113187.html implies that it is just an exception for GCC due to technical reasons, but that thread is a few years old now, and I didn't fully try to understand it yet.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc` is not an actual package. It consists of two packages that share some configuration: `gcc-initial` and `gcc-final`. Thus, you have to set

```
GCC_INITIAL_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../../submodules/gcc
GCC_FINAL_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../../submodules/gcc
```

or, to factor it a little in the same way as the in-tree packages do it:

```
GCC_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = ../../submodules/gcc
GCC_INITIAL_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = $(GCC_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR)
GCC_FINAL_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR = $(GCC_OVERRIDE_SRCDIR)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks Arnout! I should have tried that. It is going to be beautiful. The only missing thing now for perfection is not needing to build from SRCDIR out of tree instead of ugly rsync.